# Appears kernel dead when run VAE model on my Macbook m2

Tags: python, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

My device is MacBook m2, version of  tensorflow is 2.9.0
When I run the VAE model on the Jupyter notebook, it reminds that the kernel dead.

**Original codes**  [Drug Molecule Generation with VAE](https://keras.io/examples/generative/molecule_generation/)

```
vae_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=VAE_LR)

encoder = get_encoder(
    gconv_units=[9],
    adjacency_shape=(BOND_DIM, NUM_ATOMS, NUM_ATOMS),
    feature_shape=(NUM_ATOMS, ATOM_DIM),
    latent_dim=LATENT_DIM,
    dense_units=[512],
    dropout_rate=0.0,
)
decoder = get_decoder(
    dense_units=[128, 256, 512],
    dropout_rate=0.2,
    latent_dim=LATENT_DIM,
    adjacency_shape=(BOND_DIM, NUM_ATOMS, NUM_ATOMS),
    feature_shape=(NUM_ATOMS, ATOM_DIM),
)

model = MoleculeGenerator(encoder, decoder, MAX_MOLSIZE)

model.compile(vae_optimizer)
history = model.fit([adjacency_tensor, feature_tensor, qed_tensor], epochs=EPOCHS)
```

[error shown in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy1s4.png)

Hope someone could explain why this issue happens, Thanks